# Stata esttab twoway tabulate labels

Tags: latex, stata, label

Say that I have this dataset:

```
webuse union, clear
```

I want to run a tabulation:

```
tab union smsa
```

I want to export it to a .tex file and have it look similar to the above tabulation. Is there a way to have code similar to the following display the labels (`union worker` and `lives in SMSA`) automatically instead of having to hard code them in?

```
eststo clear
eststo: estpost tab union smsa
esttab est1 using "${path}/example.tex", cell(b) unstack noobs ///
    replace nonum collabels(none) eqlabels(, lhs("union worker")) ///
    mtitles("lives in SMSA")
```

Comment: Corrected `sysuse auto` to `webuse union`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify what you mean by "automatically"? I can't test this because those variables are not in the auto dataset when I load it, but you could call the variable label macro instead of the variable label explicitly:

```
eststo clear
eststo: estpost tab union smsa
esttab est1 using "${path}/example.tex", cell(b) unstack noobs ///
    replace nonum collabels(none) eqlabels(, lhs("`:variable label union'")) ///
    mtitles("`:variable label smsa'")
```

Try `help extended_fcn` for details.

Comment: @bill999 wrote `sysuse auto` but his examples follow `webuse union`.

Comment: @atkat12 By "automatically," I mean that I don't have to either write it in myself or refer to the variable label as in your solution. I would like to eliminate the possibility of switching the variables by mistake. When one does `tab var_a var_b`, the labels automatically show up in the correct place without the user needing to specify anything.